# How to write a script to install multiple things by just executing it

Tags: bash, scripting, executable

I have a server (centOS) on which I would like to install the staple development tools. Java, Tomcat, and MySql.

What is a good way to write a script that can be ran on newly spawned server so that this isn't done manually on each new server.

Would a bash script work best for this purpose? I would want the script not just tied to centOS but be able to work across different flavors of linux

Comment: You write a script to do something by writing a script that does those things (this is one of those Zen Koan kinda things), but like Sirex points out below Configuration Management tools are really the Right Way to do this these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with bash, but you likely want something more like puppet. (Try decentralised puppet and "puppet apply" runs).

Comment: +1 also I'd like to mention ansible (http://ansible.cc/) and chef (http://www.opscode.com/chef/)